# jQuery event on dynamically created div not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code that allows the user to create divs with some content in them on a page. These divs are dynamically generated and I need a click event that fires when a user clicks on any one of the dynamically generated divs.

All the dynamically created divs have `class="entry"`.

```
<div class="entry">
//some content
</div>
<div class="entry">
//some other content
</div>
//...
```

Following the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements?rq=1) my code looks like this:

```
$('body').on('click','div.event',function(){
    console.log("clicked");
    //do stuff
});
```

However this event does not seem to fire as console.log("clicked") is never executed. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

EDIT: Sorry guys it was just the typo. I cannot believe I didn't spot that before. So sorry for wasting your time, unfortunately I cannot delete the question now that people have answered it.

Comment: Typo: Change `div.event` to `div.entry`

Comment: Oh wow I cannot believe I didn't spot that for nearly an hour. So sorry for the stupid question guys.

Comment: @AZG, did it work?

Comment: @AZG if my answer works for you, mark it as a solution for your issue.

Comment: @DamienGold will do once the 10 minutes run out.

Comment: @AZG Okay, that's cool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote `event` instead of `entry`.

`$('body').on('click','div.entry',function(){
    console.log("clicked");
    //do stuff
});`

Comment: @jbman223 he is not getting downvoted, it was another guy who was getting downvoted, but he deleted his answer. The answer was actually the exact same one as Damien's answer, and also the exact same as the comment in the question. I guess it was downvoted because some1 thought: "hey he just copied that from the comments", which was not the case most likely.  Yeah.

Comment: Oh right it was you @prasad :). Too bad you got that downvote, a correct answer is a correct answer, no matter how trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to below. it should work.

```
$('document').on('click','.entry',function(){
    console.log("clicked");
    //do stuff
});
```

document will search your class name in entire document,once it finds the class name,then event gets fire.